# Any good way of using Flash components in haxe?

Tags: flash, components, haxe

I was wondering if there is any standard practice in using components in Haxe.
Searched the google and find very little on it. Apparently people ten to use ASWing and other third-party solutions.

I am mostly intersted in modyfing the components appearance in Flash (CS4) than pulling an swf file which I could include in swf-lib. Right now I am kind of forced to make it via movie clip export it, and build functionality in Haxe.
Which as you imagine is not handy and timeconsuming (especially that fl.controls used to work for me very well, I barely had to modify any mechanics, sometimes was just adding functionality).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Currently there is no other way arround this, then using swc/swf or if possible porting the code to Haxe.
Here is simple tutorial how to use AS3 written swc/swf from Haxe: http://haxe.org/doc/flash/aswingas3

Since a year or maybe even longer there is the possibility to use a swf directly from the compiler (including auto completion and type checking) by using the `--swf-lib` flag.

Comment: to ask further - am I able to alter the looks of for instance the Slider component, export it to swf and then do the generation + be able to use it with my alterations.

Comment: Ohhh I noticed its fine. A minor distraction than, but other than that totally ok.

Comment: I'm searching for the same thing one year later.  My googling led me to Arctic, http://lib.haxe.org/p/arctic - It looks like a very good effort and has some promising features, but is still immature.  Does anyone have any further thoughts on this?